# ArrayList<String[]> Sorting First Elements

Tags: java

```
public ArrayList<String[]> customerArray= new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

The first elements are String type, I want to make them Integer and sorting.

```
35 Murat Kaya 236-3446789 Address: Dikmen 4. Cadde 34/2
45 Hatice AK 568-8969746 Address: Cebeci 56 cd. 34/5
```

It is part of this file.

Comment: what do you mean by The first elements are String type do you mean `35` and `45` ?

Comment: It's of course possible, but this is the wrong way of solving the problem. Start by transforming your arrays of strings into objects of a well-defined class, with named, typed properties, and then sort these objects.

Comment: Yes, 35 and 45. Basically, I want to sort them by id number.

Comment: [`Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it like so:

```
customerArray.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> Integer.parseInt(e[0])));
```

Answer (score 1):

`customerArray.sort((sa1,sa2)->Integer.parseInt(sa1[0])-Integer.parseInt(sa2[0]));`